# DC-DC Half Bridge Converter Capacitor Selection?

Tags: capacitor, switch-mode-power-supply, dc-dc-converter

For the [image: Half bridge converter] shown in figure. How do I decide on the capacitor values C4 and C3? I know they should have a balanced voltage across them. Do I go with the regular capacitor equation to determine the value? Do I need to keep anything else in mind?

Please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: It is usually better to have a centre tapped primary to V+ with alternate switching to V- than a centre tapped cap.

Comment: otherwise.    { Zc(f) =~ RdsOn } which both are <1% of (Vout/Iout)*(Np/Ns)^2. so that source impedance is <1% of primary input impedance. This improves load regulation error to 2% best case and applies to C3,C4,Cb

Answer (score 3):

Bridge caps should be high, like 470u or 680u, depending on the input power and required input ripple. But for most applications, the filter cap can be selected according to **1uF per output watts** formula. For example, in my 400W converter design, I used two 680uF caps in series.

We always want bridge capacitors to have equal voltage across them. So don't forget to put equal resistors across C3 and C4 to guarantee dropping equal voltage across them. Or else, high tolerances of the caps (15% or even 20%) will determine the divider ratio. That resistors will also help discharging the caps. Take switching frequency into account while selecting that resistors. You want the caps to discharge before the next cycle, right?

CB is **blocking capacitor** and can be anything between 470n and 1u. But voltage rating of the cap is important and should be at least half of maximum DC bus voltage. For example, if the input varies between 185 and 265Vac then VIN(max) = 370VDC. So CB can be a 1u/250V.

Comment: Hi, Rohat. Do you have more explanation about this blocking capacitor? Is it not like normal DC blocking filter because of HB configuration,right?

Comment: @analog_designer Effectively, CB and parallel equivalent of C3-C4 (C3 + C4) will be in series (take the AC equivalent of circuit by shorting the VDC rail to ground). So, for steady-state operation, using CB will not change the overall behaviour (there are two capacitor in series) except it'll take almost all the voltage drop across itself (assuming C3+C4 >> CB). CB plays more effective role on corner cases such as shorts/overloads by isolating the primary winding from any DC component which can cause flux walking and therefore core saturation, and C3+C4 play role on start up. Nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

Normally the Capacitor values for C4 and C3 are 470uF most commontly used, the Voltage of this capacitors must be the same as the DC voltage input that you apply through this inverter since the input voltage for example 100V, this voltage will be divided to the capacitors C4 and C3 (Since this is a capacitive voltage divider) for convert this 100V DC into 50V AC Peak (Positivie waves)/50V AC Peak (Negative waves) in wish this means that your net voltage is 100V AC Peak-Peak sinusoidal, so your voltage value for your capacitors C4 and C3 could be of 80V/470uF.
Also, for you capacitor Cb, this is a coupling capacitor (In my opinion), in wish it's value it's dependant of the frequency that this inverter carries, for example: 
For coupling a 100Hz signal, a 10μF capacitor can be used.

For a 1000Hz signal, a 1μF capacitor can be used.

For a 10KHz signal, a 100nF capacitor can be used.

For a 100KHz signal, 10nF capacitor can be used.

For a 1MHz signal, a 1nF capacitor can be used.

For a 10MHz signal, a 100pF capacitor can be used.

For a 100MHz signal, a 10pF capacitor can be used.