# Half-bridge converter - formula for mid-voltage capacitors

Tags: capacitor, dc-dc-converter, bridge

I am trying to make a real DCDC half-bridge converter based on this [paper](https://koreascience.kr/article/JAKO201620240593776.pdf) and I can't find a formula for calculating those two capacitors C<sub>1</sub> and C<sub>2</sub>. In this paper the author chose C<sub>1</sub> and C<sub>2</sub> to be 3000 μF.

[image]

I found another similar question [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/259406/dc-dc-half-bridge-converter-capacitor-selection), in which a user states that "filter cap can be selected according to 1 μF per output watts formula". Considering that the paper which I read studies a 3 kW converter, the previous statement is correct.

What is the formula, so that I can finally understand the complete design?

Comment: Why not use a simulator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research which took me quite some time, I managed to perfectly  understand and formulate an answer. It's all down to three question which I must ask myself designing the converter:

- What is the maximum permissible Voltage drop on the capacitor? - meaning what is the range of potential difference from which I want to "extract" my energy?
- What is the maximum current that I will have in primary?
- What is the pulse duration of my converter "supplying" that charge?

Let's say that these are my converter parameters:

[image]

The worst case of charging and discharging will be selected, meaning that the maximum current in primary will be considered corresponding with its duty cycle.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

They probably chose 3000 µF because they're doubling for mains rectification.

Minimum value, assuming DC input, depends on frequency, tolerable ripple, and output current.  So, in the ballpark of
$$C = \frac{I_\textrm{out}}{2 \pi F V_\textrm{ripple}}$$